# Cmake : FetchContent_Declare protobuf + grpc error "cannot create target libprotobuf-lite"

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm trying to get protobuf(actually, I need protoc) and grpc during cmake configuration time.
I tried to download sources from github via FetchContent_Declare() macro.

My simple cmake project :

- **CMakeLists.txt :**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

#enable verbose makefiles
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON CACHE BOOL "ON")

include(cmake/dependencies.cmake)

set(ASSURE_LIBRARY_NAME "assure")
set(ASSURE_LIBRARY_VERSION "1.0.0")

project(assure 
        LANGUAGES CXX
        VERSION ${ASSURE_LIBRARY_VERSION})

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

- **cmake/dependencies.cmake** :

```
include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_BASE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty)

## PROTOBUF ##
FetchContent_Declare(
        protobuf-git
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
        GIT_TAG        main
        SOURCE_SUBDIR  cmake
        GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(protobuf-git)
## END PROTOBUF ##

## GRPC ##
FetchContent_Declare(
        grpc-git
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
        GIT_TAG        master
        GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(grpc-git)
## END GRPC ##
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting an error pointing to duplicating targets in protobuf and grpc :

```
1> [CMake] CMake Error at 3rdparty/grpc-git-src/third_party/protobuf/cmake/libprotobuf-lite.cmake:67 (add_library):
1> [CMake]   add_library cannot create target "libprotobuf-lite" because another target
1> [CMake]   with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library
1> [CMake]   created in source directory
...
1> [CMake]   See documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   3rdparty/grpc-git-src/third_party/protobuf/cmake/CMakeLists.txt:260 (include)
1> [CMake] CMake Error at 3rdparty/grpc-git-src/third_party/protobuf/cmake/libprotobuf.cmake:118 (add_library):
1> [CMake]   add_library cannot create target "libprotobuf" because another target with
1> [CMake]   the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static library
1> [CMake]   created in source directory
```

Is there any way to workaround duplicating targets in subprojects in cmake ?

Comment: grpc depends on protobuf. have you tried adding grpc alone?

Comment: yes, I finally ended with grpc only and building+installing of grpc during configuration time. PS : I tried to build grpc with protobuf dependency as a "package" but find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED) from grpc fails with error of missing protobuf-config.cmake.